# $\exists$ left inverse of a square matrix $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$ right inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have proved that if a square $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$ has a right and left inverse, then these are equal and form an inverse matrix of $A$.

However I'm interested in the following implication:

Suppose a left inverse $B$ of a square $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$ exist. Does this imply that a right inverse $C$ of $A$ exist ?

Also, if this is true - is the implication also true in the case of a right inverse $B$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and yes. The easiest way to see it is probably to consider the linear maps induced by the matrices.

Comment: At the risk of repeating other answers already given, a function has a left inverse iff it's injective; a function has a right inverse iff it's surjective; and a linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension is injective iff it's surjective.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/472818

Answer (score 4):

Yes, If $A$ has a left-inverse $B$, then $BA = I$, and so $A$ is injective (as a linear map). But it is a linear operator on a finite dimensional space, so it is also surjective, and so it has a right-inverse.

Comment: Hi Prahlad. I've never been thinking of matrices like this. However if $A$ was a traditional function, yes if it is surjective indeed it has a right inverse. However how do I construct the right inverse of $A$ in the matrix case ? Doing it for a traditional function I choose some element in the domain that has image equal to the input.

Comment: Once you know it has a right inverse, then you can check that the right-inverse must equal the left-inverse, and so $B$ is the right-inverse!

Comment: But you have just proved that it is a matrix. In fact, you have proved that it is $B$!

Comment: So I can say $f: R^{n \cdot n} \rightarrow R^{n \cdot n}$ and then $BX = B(Af(X)) = (BA)f(X) = (I)f(X) = f(X)$, where $R^{n \cdot n}$ denote the set of $n$ x $n$ matrices and $X \in R^{n \cdot n}$. The value of the theoretical right inverse $f(X)$ is the same as the the matrix product $BX$ for every $X \in R^{n \cdot n}$. Hence the linear map $B$ and $f$ are equal and can be substituted for one another. What I proved before needed some work to prove that $f$ is in fact $B$ - This is what I've done now ? Also are there other ways of proving this ? If my proof is right, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the matrix $A$ has a left inverse $B$, such that $BA=I$. The determinant of a matrix product is the product of the factors' determinants, and so
$\left\lvert BA \right\rvert=\left\lvert B \right\rvert \left\lvert A \right\rvert=\left\lvert I \right\rvert=1$.
Thus,both the inverse and the original matrix must be non-singular (in the sense of having non-null determinant). Since $A$ is non-singular, we can build
$$D=\frac{1}{\left\lvert A \right\rvert}A^{adj}$$
where $A^{adj}$ is the adjoint (transposed) matrix or cofactors of $A$. It's not difficult to check that $A D=I$. So, $A$ has a right inverse given by $D$.

Now, assume $A$ has a right inverse $R$, so that $AR=I$. Again, by properties of the determinant of a matrix product, it must be the case that both $A$ and $R$ are non-singular. Thus, we can find the right-inverse $R^{-1}$ for $R$ as we found $D$ before. Then,
$$A R =I\\
R A R =R I=R\\
R A R R^{-1}=R R^{-1}=I\\
R A=I
$$
and so, $R$ is also a left inverse.